# Test Suit, Test Module, Test Block, Test Scenario and Test Cases

Tags: testing, module, block, test-suite, scenarios

Please let me know what is the definition of ***Test Suit, Test Module, Test Block, Test Scenario and Test Cases***, and what is the relation between them?

Thanks,
Somnath

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should know about asking for definitions is that words have multiple meanings depending on their context. If I give you an answer about what a Test Suite is (I assume you don't mean Suit as in a Suit and Tie) or a Module is and you take those definitions without thinking or applying them to your context, you won't make any sense. In fact you'll look stupid to anyone who knows better.

It's a better idea to try to understand how others are using the words and when. If you are in a team and they use a word you don't understand - ask. Lots of people use these words in different ways with different contexts and have different meanings. If you want to learn more, do some searches around for how people use those words in other contexts and see if there are any similarities or differences.

At the very least this should help you ask better questions.

Answer (score -1):

There is TONS of information about testing on the internet. All the things you ask can be easily found if you google them. Have you even tried searching a bit?

I'm sorry but I would vote this question down but I can't because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hey NielsC, Thanks for ur reply....actually I was not getting any definition for Test Block and Test Module. That is why I thought putting my question in a forum would help me.

Comment: Well that's different then. I know what a Test Suit is and a Test scenario and Test case are basically the same. But where did you hear or read Test module and Test block? I've personally never heard of it although I've been taught unit testing at school. Maybe they mean a single unit test with a Test block.